# Setting value from cookies to TextField<Long> in Wicket

Tags: java, forms, cookies, wicket

I face following problem:

I have wicket page with filter. Filter is the form component which contains this TextField:

```
TextField<Long> categoryField = new TextField<Long>("categoryId", 
     BindingModel.of(model, binding.categoryId()), 
     Long.class);
add(categoryField );
```

I want to allow user to remember his last filter options so I store field values in cookies

```
CookieUtils utils = new CookieUtils();
utils.save(categoryField);
```

This works fine and field value is store in cookies. But problem is when I want to read value from cookies and set it to component via

```
utils.load(categoryField);
```

then I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at cz.myproject.domain.MyFilterBindingPath$CategoryIdBinding.setWithRoot(MyFilterBindingPath.java:494)
    at cz.myproject.binding.BindingModel.setObject(BindingModel.java:66)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3061)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelObject(FormComponent.java:1560)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1104)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelValue(FormComponent.java:1046)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.cookies.CookieUtils.load(CookieUtils.java:135)
```

thank you for help

Comment: What is formComponent? This should fail already during conversion (before updateModel) so maybe formComponent is not typed in the same way the categoryField is.

Comment: Sorry it was mistake in the text...

Comment: The `ClassCastException` was raised in your(?) `cz.myproject` code. We might need to see a relevant code extract to see what is going on.

Comment: I checked similar use-case in our code and it works correctly. Please share the relevant code from stacktrace (model).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit incomplete. It doesn't show the implementation of BindingModel. Even if you look to TextField it expects as a model any implementation of IModel, but CookieUtil.load() returns String. So the return type really cannot be cast from String to Long. Change your model implementation to be type safe.